# Add a simple GIF to a class

Tags: java, class, file-io, gif

I am in my programming 2 class and the professor wants us to make a class that will eventually develop into a game. The problem that I am having is that I dont know how to add the file to the class so that when I use the tester I get no errors. I dont have to do anything with the file, yet. I just need to make a couple of instances in the tester after my myPlayer2 but Im not sure how to go about this. I hope this and my code makes sense. Thank you.

```
import java.io.File;



public class myPlayer {

private String name;
private String gender;
private String role;
private int health;
private String state;
private File sprite = new File("MarioSprite.gif");
/**
 * constructor for the game player
 * @param name-- the players name
 * @param gender -- the players gender
 * @param role -- role such as boss, healer, demon, knight
 * @param health -- percentage of health
 * @param state -- whether player is alive, dead, active, inactive, sleeping
 * @param sprite -- this is the sprite file for the class
 */

// the file name is MarioSprite.gif 

public myPlayer(){
    name = " unknown";
    gender = " unknown";
    role = " not defined";
    health =  0;
    state = " not defined";
    sprite = null;
}
public myPlayer(String name, String gender, String role, int health, String state, File sprite){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.role = role;
    this.health = health;
    this.state = state;
    this.sprite = sprite;
}
/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
/**
 * @param  the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
/**
 * @return the gender
 */
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
/**
 * @param  the gender to set
 */
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
/**
 * @return the role
 */
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
/**
 * @param  the role to set
 */
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
/**
 * @return the health
 */
public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}
/**
 * @param  the health to set
 */
public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}
/**
 * @return the state
 */
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
/**
 * @param  the state to set
 */
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
/**
 * @return the sprite
 */
public File getSprite() {
    return sprite;
}
/**
 * @param  the sprite to set
 */
public void setSprite(File sprite) {
    this.sprite = sprite;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "myPlayer [name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + ", role="
            + role + ", health=" + health + ", state=" + state
            + ", sprite=" + sprite + "]";
}
}

public class myPlayerTester {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    myPlayer myPlayer1, myPlayer2, myPlayer3, myPlayer4;

    myPlayer1 = new myPlayer();

    System.out.println(myPlayer1);

    myPlayer2 = new myPlayer("SteveO", "Male", "demon", 99, "live", null );

    System.out.println(myPlayer2);

    myPlayer3 = new myPlayer("Gandolf", "Female", "demon", 93, "live", null);

    System.out.println(myPlayer3);

    myPlayer4 = new myPlayer("Roger", "Female", "demon", 69, "inactive", null);

    System.out.println(myPlayer4);




}
```

}

Comment: I just dont want the myPlayer2 in the tester to display null, I want it to reference somehow the file that I had created instead of null. Hope that clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simple methods from File

```
        File file = new File("folder/folder/folder/file.gif");
        //absolute path
        file.getAbsolutePath();
        //path
        file.getPath();
```

Use this on your test class and put object in myPlayer2 constructor.

In you toString() method, in variable

> sprite

use

> sprite.getPath()  or  sprite.getAbsolutePath();

for display path to your file in string format.

If you want use stream for reading bytes, try this

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("folder/folder/folder/file.gif"));
```

Comment: I put the file.getPath() in the toString part in the class. When I put the same thing in the tester under myPlayer2 it asks me to change it to a String in Eclipse. It looks like this:  myPlayer2 = new myPlayer("SteveO", "Male", "demon", 99, "live", sprite.getPath() );

Comment: Yes, if you put sprite.getPath() to myPlayer, actualy you put String, not File. If you want use File in constructor, put File and in toString method use sprite.getPath(). If you want use String in constructor - change your constractor arguments.